# Authenticating Ember-CLI and simple-auth against remote rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, devise

I have two separate apps, one is a rails api and the other is an ember-cli based client app to consume the api.  The issue I'm having is trying to figure out how to send the authentication requests to the rails app (using devise, btw).  Anyone have any insight or links to some examples of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that a) your Rails app has CORS enabled (http://enable-cors.org) and allows requests from the Ember app's origin and b) whitelist the Rails app's origin (http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Configuration-crossOriginWhitelist) so that Ember Simple Auth will actually authenticate requests to the Rails app.